# What to use instead of Promise.all() when you want all results regardless of any rejections

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm using the Bluebird promise library in a node.js project.  I have two operations that both return promises and I want to know when both are done, whether resolved or rejected and I need the return values from both.  I'm reading the contents of multiple files and some of the files may not exist and that's an OK condition, so though `fs.readFileAsync()` will fail if the file doesn't exist, I still need the results of the other read operation.

`Promise.all(p1, p2)` will reject if either p1 or p2 rejects and I don't think I'll necessarily get the data from the other one.

Of all the other Bluebird operations (`.some()`, `.any()`, `.settle()`, etc...) which is most appropriate to this situation?  And, how is the data passed back such that you can tell which ones succeeded and which ones didn't?

Comment: different kind of question: if you're comfortable with callbacks and you're even writing code with promises, why would you bother with `fs.readFileSync` instead of just using `fs.readFile`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - I'm using `fs.readFileAsync` which returns a promise (it's the promisified version of `fs.readFile`, not a callback version) and is asynchronous.  This is different than `fs.readFileSync` which is synchronous (doesn't use callbacks or promises).  I'm using promises because they are much easier to do proper error handling on and when you're waiting for multiple async things to be done, they are a ton easier.

Comment: hah, completely missed that "A". Shows how much I use plain node >_>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be indeed be `.settle`. Settle takes an array of promises and returns `PromiseInspection` instances for all of them when they *resolve*. You can then check if they're fulfilled or rejected and extract their value.

For example:

```
Promise.settle(['a.txt', 'b.txt'].map(fs.readFileAsync)).then(function(results){
    // results is a PromiseInspetion array
    console.log(results[0].isFulfilled()); // returns true if was successful
    console.log(results[0].value()); // the promise's return value
});
```

Your use case is pretty much what `Promise.settle` exists for.

Comment: Thx - I was just posting my own answer while you were posting yours.  I eventually figured out `.settle()`, but there is zero documentation on how to use it so it took me hours in the debugger to finally figure out something workable.  I literally had to examine the arguments in the debugger to find out how to get the data out of them.  That piece of doc could seriously use a few good examples.  Also, how is one supposed to know that `.settle()` takes a second argument that's a function that will be called on each item in the array?  is that explained somewhere for `.settle()`?

Comment: Also, does `.settle()` reject if all input promises are rejected, but fulfills if at least one is filfilled?  It would also be useful to see that in the doc.

Comment: @jfriend00 all Bluebird functions have a static version of them alongside the instance version. You have `Promise.map(arr, fn)` and `promiseArr.map(fn)` `Promise.filter(arr, fn)` and `promiseArr.filter(fn)` etc. I'll edit the documentation to add an example for settle.

Comment: @jfriend00 settle always fulfills, it will fulfill with all `PromiseInspection` rejected.

Comment: Hmmm.  OK, that's another good thing to know.  Glad you will be improving the doc.  Please note that I couldn't figure out what a `PromiseInspection` was (until I looked at it in the debugger) or how to use it.  It is referred to exactly once in `.settle()` with a link to some other place in the doc that doesn't use that word.  Even a Google search didn't reveal helpful info.  I was quite confused.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks a lot for the feedback, I will definitely entertain (and appreciate) doc pull requests so please do make them if you think anything else can/should be clarified. An issue would also work if you think something is unclear but don't feel like making a PR. I've made a recent change here: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/commit/d71ff5ad35c25b676d95af71c9a199494d37bc1f#diff-88333ba11114e014e87198d04680144d let me know if you think it clarifies `.settle` well enough.

Comment: Excellent improvement!  Thx.  I'm still learning github so might be better with filing an issue for now.  You might show that `r.value()` should only be accessed inside an `if (r.fulfilled())` since you pretty much have to use it that way with `.settle()` since you can't already know its state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61651/discussion-between-benjamin-gruenbaum-and-jfriend00).

Comment: settle doesn't take any function it just takes an array?

Comment: @Esailija Oh yeah, that wouldn't make any sense, settle just settles the values. I love how we've had this whole debate and I haven't noticed :D

Answer (score 0):

Only by trying different options and then ultimately stepping through code in the debugger, I figured out how to do this using `.settle()`:

```
// display log files
app.get('/logs', function(req, res) {
    var p1 = fs.readFileAsync("/home/pi/logs/fan-control.log");
    var p2 = fs.readFileAsync("/home/pi/logs/fan-control.err");
    Promise.settle([p1, p2]).spread(function(logFile, errFile) {
        var templateData = {logData: "", errData: ""};
        if (logFile.isFulfilled()) {
            templateData.logData = logFile.value();
        }
        if (errFile.isFulfilled()) {
            templateData.errData = errFile.value();
        }
        res.render('logs', templateData);
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log("err getting log files");
        // figure out what to display here
        res.render(e);
    });
});
```

If anyone from the Bluebird team comes along, the doc for how to use `.settle()` is missing about 2/3 of what is needed to understand how to use it.  It makes reference to a `PromiseInspection`, but makes no reference on how to use that.  A simple code example in the doc for `.settle()` and for how you examine the results that `.settle()` returns would have saved hours of time.